# Modulus and moduli problem of complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

The moduli of two complex numbers are less than unity. The the modulus of the sum of these complex number

(a) less than unity

(b) greater than unity

(c) equal to unity

(d) any of a,b,c

Please guide...

Comment: could you determine module of each  complex number?for example what is moduli of $a+b*i$?

Comment: Just work with real numbers.

Answer (score 4):

(a) $0+0$

(b) $0.9+0.9$

(c) $0.5+0.5$

(d) Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Let $z_1=r_1(\cos\theta_1+i\sin\theta_1)$ and  $z_2=r_2(\cos\theta_2+i\sin\theta_2)$ where $r_1,r_2<1$

So, $z_1+z_2=r_1\cos\theta_1+r_2\cos\theta_2+i(r_1\sin\theta_1+r_2\sin\theta_2)$

$|z_1+z_2|^2$
$=(r_1\cos\theta_1+r_2\cos\theta_2)^2+(r_1\sin\theta_1+r_2\sin\theta_2)^2$
$=r_1^2+r_2^2+2r_1r_2\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$

Now,  $$-1\le \cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)\le 1$$

$$\implies r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2\le r_1^2+r_2^2+2r_1r_2\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)\le r_1^2+r_2^2+2r_1r_2$$

$$\implies (r_2-r_1)^2\le |z_1+z_2|^2\le (r_2+r_1)^2$$

So, $|z_1+z_2|=r_2+r_1$ if $\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)=1\iff \theta_1=\theta_2$

As $0\le r_1,r_2<1\implies 0\le r_1+r_2<2$

So, $|z_1+z_2|$ can lie $\in [0,2)$